# How do I get extract a table from an HTML Page as a data.frame using XML and Rcurl in R

Tags: html, r, xml, rcurl

I need to extract a table as a data.frame from the following HTML Page:

https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank.html

Comment: Please help.....

Answer (score 1):

That table has live content, so you need a headless browser, Rselenium should be your first choice. Also, you need rvest to extract the table

Note: After you navigate to that page, there will be a transition page, you can click continue manually or just wait a few seconds.
[image: This page will pop up]

**Code:**

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

remDr <-rsDriver(port = 4445L,browser = "chrome")
myclient <- remDr$client
#navigate to that page
#After navigate to that page,you need to manually click "continue button" or select and click it with css or just wait a few seconds
myclient$navigate("https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank")
#you need to scroll down several times, or you will get only top 10 in the list
replicate(20,myclient$sendKeysToActiveElement(list(key="page_down")))
#get pagesource
mypagesource <- unlist(myclient$getPageSource())
#Using rvest to extract table
mytable <-read_html(mypagesource) %>% html_node("#the_list") %>% html_table()


> str(mytable)
'data.frame':   109 obs. of  8 variables:
    $                    : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ Rank               : chr  "#1" "#2" "#3" "#4" ...
$ Brand              : chr  "Apple" "Google" "Microsoft" "Facebook" ...
$ Brand Value        : chr  "$170 B" "$101.8 B" "$87 B" "$73.5 B" ...
$ 1-Yr Value Change  : chr  "10%" "23%" "16%" "40%" ...
$ Brand Revenue      : chr  "$214.2 B" "$80.5 B" "$85.3 B" "$25.6 B" ...
$ Company Advertising: chr  "$1.8 B" "$3.9 B" "$1.6 B" "$310 M" ...
$ Industry           : chr  "Technology" "Technology" "Technology" "Technology" ...
```

Then you can clean the data afterwards:
[image: datatable]

Introduction and tutorials to those packages:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html
https://stat4701.github.io/edav/2015/04/02/rvest_tutorial/

Comment: Thank you so much. The code worked like a charm.